# How do I change my SMTP email to identify my website by domain name rather than IP address?

Tags: mailgun, tiki-wiki

This may be a dumb question, but how do I configure my SMTP email to identify my website by domain name rather than IP address?

I'm currently running Tiki Wiki (certified by Bitnami) on Google Cloud Compute. I had no major issues setting up Mailgun, but when my website sends emails, the only indication that it's from my website is in the sender address. Everything else identifies the website by IP address.

Is there something I need to change in MyPhPAdmin? Or with Mailgun?

Comment: can you specify what you mean by everything else in "Everything else identifies the website by IP address"?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Tiki mail sending in SMTP mode, then you can specify the "Local server name" on the General Control Panel (`zend_mail_smtp_helo`), might that be what you're looking for?

Comment: This is documented in the article https://doc.tiki.org/General-Preferences